# Laravel Model binding not working after upgrade to 5.3

Tags: laravel, model, laravel-routing, laravel-5.3

[image]

I have Bind Model from Route service provider like this

```
class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

   public function boot(){
        parent::boot();
        Route::model('job_title', \Cgs\Modules\JobTitle\Models\JobTitle::class);   
   }
```

}

and route likes this

```
Route::get('edit/{job_title}', ['as' => 'job.title.edit', 'uses' => 'JobTitleController@edit', 'middleware' => ['permission:job-title-edit']]);
```

Edit method

```
public function edit(JobTitle $jobtitle)
{
    dd($jobtitle);
}
```

Above code give error
No query results for model [Cgs\Modules\JobTitle\Models\JobTitle]

When I check in debugger I see it is binding multiple times first correct and second it takes as json. Please help with multiple binding issue.

Comment: I don't think this error isn't due to your route model binding,could you post the `edit()` method of your `JobTitleController`?

Comment: sure let me add code for edit method.